# Is it possible to confine regression output to some conditions in an ANN?

Tags: neural-network

I have a NN that accepts amount spent as input, and predicts the number of clothing items bought as a multi-target regression problem (see: [How to count categorization instances in a NN?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49518/how-to-count-categorization-instances-in-a-nn)).

Each clothing item however has a fixed value, and it would make no sense for the NN to predict a sequence of purchased items which has a different value to the input budget. Is there any way I can convey this information to the NN to either force it to confine its output to match the dollar amount of the input, or to assist it in its training?